# Bring back RBJ's comment

Tags: support, comments

Deleted from [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/78513/50076). Can it be brought back, and given protected status?

Do it and I won't cuss for 365 days. Non-contiguous days, but still.

Comment: *//" Non-contiguous days, but still."//* - - - - giggle giggle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tempting as your offer is, unfortunately I can't comply. I can't see **how** to undelete the comment. Normally, when I hover over the comment it gives me extra options, but there's nothing here.

Comment: Darn. I'll try to reach for the stars.

Comment: [Hmm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22233/612423)... now that I think of it, my cuss-deleted comments were on HNQs. I assumed it was you - if not, it'd be good to know.

Comment: The odd thing is, I have zero idea who `starball` is. They're not a mod, of any stripe. The SE employees have a different annotation from the mod diamond, but they're clearly shown.

Comment: [12 accepted flags](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/66195/starball?tab=topactivity), but no mod badge (Sheriff) anywhere, and joined this network 4 months ago (March)... does it credit the flagger? And since it's easy to mis-read, just a PS that my previous comment asked something.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking?  Usually when someone flags something, I see who flagged it, but the deletion is credited "publicly" (to those with enough rep) to me (or another mod). The person doing the flagging never gets credited, unless they're a mod.

Comment: I'll ask at MSE. What I'm asking you is, if you were one who deleted a bunch of my comments for having "shit"-and-friends in it. E.g. [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/87254/50076) I flagged every other comment for a criterion that makes sense, after seeing mine deleted - off-topic/not-needed - but they're still there.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon It looks like I deleted some comments by *others* in that thread, but it says I didn't delete your comment that was deleted there.  Again, a low-rep user is credited with deleting it.  I'm wondering if there's a bug in the attributions? Very odd.

Comment: For comments that meet certain criteria, a single flag will automatically cause the comment to be deleted, as mentioned [here on MSE by Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99853/335251). I'm guessing that's what happened here.

Comment: @V2Blast Cool! Thanks for the explanation.